# Detect button click with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, user-interface, socket.io

Is there a way to detect a button press with Node.JS? I want to run a function when a certain button is pressed. If possible, preferably without Socket.IO.

Comment: Node.JS is server-side, you'll need an AJAX call to run node code on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clientside:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $.post('/thing', {data: 'blah'}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}, 'json');
```

serverside:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlEncoded());
app.post('/thing', function (req, res, next) {
  var data = myFunction(req.body);
  res.json(data);
});
```

Comment: Works, but it only works about 6 times then you have to refresh.